# Коротковорсовый или коротковорсный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, суффиксы, выбор-варианта

Подскажите, какой вариант является предпочтительным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словари находят оба варианта, но "коротковорсовый" находится (поиском в гугле) в большем количестве словарей. Слова "ворсовый" и "безворсовый" содержатся во всех основных словарях, поэтому я при прочих равных отдал бы преимущество варианту **коротковорсовый**.